# Generic implementation where type could be one of two

Tags: c#

So Im getting back into c# again, and I encountered the following issue :

I want to create a generic function that can recieve one of two types, something around these lines :

```
public void Remove<T> (T inputValue) where T : (int or string)
```

I was quite surprised that I couldnt find any straight forward solution to this.

Appreciate your help or a link to somewhere the topic has been touched.
Thanks!

Comment: I think an overload would be the best option here

Comment: Neither `int` nor `string` can be subclassed, so there's not much generic about your implementation.

Comment: Agree with @Jaxi. You can't limit generics in such a way.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: @Jaxi I wanted to avoid overloading, just to see if it can be done. Got my answer, thanks.